# Sending a large amount of mail via Sendgrid with Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, json, sendgrid

As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to send daily newsletters via sendgrid with Rails, and I'm generating a large Array of Json objects (around 20 000).
What is the best practice of temporary storing this array which is needed only to build the email format, and no more after the emails list are sent.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The least harmful way of dealing with any kind of asynchronous task, like sending one or thousands of emails, is using a queue.

If you are using the most recent versions of Rails, you should check it out ActiveJobs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

If not, there are various gems that covers the same situation. The one that people uses the most is Sidekiq: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Basically, you put a task on a queue that will be consumed outside of the scope of your application. When there is no more task to perform, it will just wait for more on the background.